# How do I solve the error at the datanode log during Hadoop configuration?

Tags: hadoop, datanode

I installed Hadoop in my windows system. Only namenode and resource manager services are running. Remaining services like DataNode, SecondaryNameNode and NodeManager daemons are not visible while using jps cmd. The following error throws in the DataNode log;

**Error:**

```
2019-09-27 11:38:04,881 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker.check(StorageLocationChecker.java:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2776)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2733)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2877)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2901)
2019-09-27 11:38:04,881 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
2019-09-27 11:38:04,881 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Comment: This is saying that your local harddrive is unhealthy when inspected by Hadoop. Please show your hdfs-site.xml

Comment: I cleared the error in the DataNode log. Still, only three sources are running; remaining NodeManager and SecondaryNameNode are not getting started.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the failure in the mounted disk in DN.

First, you can check the status of the mounted disk in the data node. (Any unhealthy, RO or corrupted disk)

> CMD:  cat /etc/fstab 
>        or   mount

If more than one disk has issue (depends upon *dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated*  value) the data node going down.

Here, as per the above log:

volumes configured: 1,
volumes failed: 1

So, No active disk in DN. Its shutdown.

[NOTE](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml):

we can control the mounting disk in DN via ***dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated*** in *hdfs-default.xml*

It defines the number of volumes that are allowed to fail before a datanode stops offering service. any volume failure will cause a datanode to shutdown. By default, its zero

Comment: Now the DataNode is running fine. Still, NodeManager and SecondaryNameNode services are not getting started. Both these nodes are failed to start with an error.